# How to zip a set of lists which store in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know it can `zip` a list with `zip(list1,list2,list3)` but this way need to code the name of list directly

but if I need to store many list into another `bigList`

How to zip all the lists in `bigList`?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use sequence unpacking:

```
zip(*list_of_list)
```

What the star (*) does is it takes a sequence, and passes each of it's elements to the function as separate positional arguments.

You can also take a look at http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists